# Generating Simple Graphics In Java

Tags: java, android, image, gradient

I am just about to start porting over my iPhone application Android, but I'm finding it hard to get to grips with it.

Right now I'm trying to get the basic screens looking right before I start the back end, but have hit a brick wall with the whole, flexible layout.

I am trying to generate a simple gradient with a semi-transparent white highlight and a black bottom border to use throughout the app, but because the project will be used multiple times for many many apps with a multitude of colours, I want to do this in code rather than Photoshop.

This was easy to accomplish in OBJ-C but I've hit a brick wall before I've even started now.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve.

[image: Example of attempt]

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: *"a simple gradient with a semi-transparent white highlight and a black bottom border"* If you already have this in your iOS version, how about posting a screenshot so we can get an exact idea?

Comment: @Tim Added a screenshot to my question

Answer (score 0):

Declare an xml with a `shape` and save it in your drawables folder. Then apply that drawable to your views like any other drawable/image.

**graphic.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#fa8c5e"
        android:endColor="#ee9e6a"
        android:angle="90"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) you can have a look at the syntax for tuning your shape.